# Cross domain ajax causing issues to render data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I trying to capture data from an HTML form which will be placed on another website. From that form I need to capture data into my website. But when I tried jQuery Ajax call for cross domain it shows me 302 error with no response.

I've tried this

```
$('button[type="button"]').on('click', function(){
        var data = $('.data-capture-form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url: 'http://prospectbank.co.uk/leads/test',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            crossDomain : true,
            data : data,
            contentType: 'application/jsonp'
        }).done(function(res){
            var resp = $.parseJSON(res);
            console.log(resp);
        });
    });
```

Where is problem with this code? Any help?

***[Fiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/m0rbv8eL/5/)***

Comment: JavaScript cannot make requests to third party domains due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), unless JSONP or CORS are supported by the request recipient. In this case it appears they are not. You need to use a server-side proxy to make the request for you

Comment: How to use JSONP or CORS? any link?

Comment: The recipient server doesn't support them. You need to make the request server-side instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server, add the following header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

And then make JSONP calls

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  ...... etc ....
```

If you do not have access to the external server, you have to direct the request to your server and then make a proxied call to the external server.

Comment: I'm using cakephp .. where to add this "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"?